# Can karate use Object.assign? and How to use in Karate?

Tags: karate, assign

I want to use Object.assign() function in Karate, I tried use it directly, or use it in a function, but no one can work.

So I want to know:

Can karate use Object.assign?

and How to use it in Karate?

```
* def fn = function(target, source) {return Object.assign(target, source)}
* def result = fn(clonePagePayload, sourcePayload)
* print result
```

The error is

```
* def result = fn(clonePagePayload, sourcePayload)
js failed:
>>>>
01: fn(clonePagePayload, sourcePayload)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: com.oracle.truffle.api.dsl.UnsupportedSpecializationException: Unexpected values provided for ExportValueNodeGen@1e721583: [111, JSUndefined, false], [String,Nullish,Boolean]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use [`karate.merge()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-merge) instead.

Example:

```
* def foo = { a: 1 }
* def bar = { b: 2 }
* def baz = karate.merge(foo, bar)
* match baz == { a: 1, b: 2 }
```